# using WebClient and getpage

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to get information from a Html page using WebClient but I don't manage to get the correct page. It's not waiting for the query to be finished.
Anyone has an idea? **It must be linked to the website I'm trying to read. For others website my code is working**
Here an extract of the code I use to get the Html page

```
public void initWebClient() {
    WebClient _webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10);
    _webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    _webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    _webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    _webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    _webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
    _webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
    try {
        HtmlPage _pageRecherche = (HtmlPage) _webClient.getPage("https://www.blablacar.fr/trajets/paris/lyon/#?fn=PAris&fc=48.856614%7C2.352222&fcc=FR&fp=0&tn=LYON&tc=45.764043%7C4.835659&tcc=FR&tp=0&db=25%2F05%2F2017&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1");
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Use this code block inside the try-catch block not outside. If this fails check with another OS.

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)     webClient.getPage("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login");
        System.out.println("Yeyy! :) Loaded Page!");
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but it's still the same problem. I think it's specific to the website: "https://www.blablacar.fr/trajets/paris/lyon/#?fn=PAris&fc=48.856614%7C2.352222&fcc=FR&fp=0&tn=LYON&tc=45.764043%7C4.835659&tcc=FR&tp=0&db=25%2F05%2F2017&sort=trip_date&order=asc&limit=10&page=1" What do you mean by other OS? I have already try on Ubuntu and windows